# Structuring PHP array for use in SOAP with WSDL

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, soapserver

I am writing a SoapServer with PHP 5.2 to return a list of vacancies to another application. My WSDL doc requires a complex type along the lines of:

```
<xsd:element name="Vacancies">                            
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>  
      <xsd:element name="Vacancy" type="ns:VacancyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

My function is generating a large, nested array to assemble each vacancy and then returning the array of arrays (ie: vacancies) to the SoapServer.

Unfortunately, each array is indexed. So each VacancyType element within Vacancies has a unique index. This seems to throw the WSDL definition off and the data returned to me simply throws a parse error. I'd normally use associative arrays for key pair values, but as I'm dealing with n instances of VacancyType that wouldn't work as there wouldn't be a unique reference.

Is there a known workaround for this kind of scenario (eg: maybe an object), or should I rework my WSDL doc to cater for indexed arrays?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your data structure better? What's the relationship between Vacancy and Type? A vacancy can have multiple types? Maybe you could add a sample of your array to the question.

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit misleading, VacancyType refers to an XSD definition for a complex type (I don't think I need to detail it). For all intents and purposes it might as well be called Vacancy.

The response for this function should return something like:

* Vacancies
    * VacancyType
        * data within this...
    * VacancyType
        * data within this...
    * VacancyType
        * data within this...

I build this with an array and let the SoapServer convert this into an appropriate response based on the WSDL, but it's struggling with an indexed array of VacancyType

Comment: Where is the problem occurring? Marshaling your array to a SOAPRequest? Wouldn't this just be a series of nested Vacancy objects?

Comment: It seems that PHP doesn't have support for things such as lists - which is really what I needed. This means I will probably need to amend my WSDL doc for the service to include some kind of index. Easy enough to ignore at the other end I guess

Answer (score 1):

According to http://sam.xnet.tk/post/15/php-soap-server-part-2/ the rpc/literal style is working with xsd sequence. However, i cannot make it work with document/literal wrapped style, too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you gave nuSAOP a try? Requires no other installed PHP libs:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

According to PHP documentation, PHP supports *subsets* of SOAP 1.1, SOAP 1.2 and WSDL 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

After all, I have found a solution: I construct XML by mysefl and use

```
new SoapVar('<myitem>...</myitem><myitem>...</myitem>', XSD_ANYXML);
```